# Image processing for barcode detection

Tags: java, barcode, zxing

What would be the best way to alter an image to make it easier for zxing to detect the barcode?

And how can I alter an image in such a way in java?

I tried using RescaleOp to change the contrast, but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no operation that will improve detection, in general. It already accounts for contrast, and brightening operations will just reduce the dynamic range in the image. Tint doesn't matter.

For large and noisy images, it is possible that scaling it down, or applying a light blur, helps more than it hurts by blurring noise more than it blurs edges. However this operation will do more harm than good on your average, normal camera image.

Comment: I resized the image and ran it trough a grayscale thing that increased the contrast and it seemed to work.

Comment: It is the resize that had any effect.

Comment: Not always. I use a loop that changes the offset of what turns white and what turns black. `if(color.getRed<x && color.getBlue<x && color.getGreen<x) color = 0x000000 else color = 0xFFFFFF` 

Depending on the quality of of the picture it has to run for a while.

Comment: OK, you're doing your own binarization then. In general you should let the library do that, but you may surely find that if you know more about your image and its characteristics that you can binarize it better than the library.

Comment: I must admit that I know very little about this, however, what I did seemed to work better than just leaving it up to the library. It is very slow though.